# Show layout bounds does not show on compose layout

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have trouble with layout bounds and compose that when I activate or deactivate "Show layout bounds", I have to restart app (activity) otherwise it doesn't work

[image: after restart]
[image: after apply show layout bounds without restart]

Test on Nokia 7.2 Android 10, Google emulator Android 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is fixed on newer API.

Answer (score 3):

That is correct!

Note however that you can use the Layout Inspector in Android Studio to show the bounds.

You can find it under `Tools` > `Layout Inspector`

More information ca be found on the [Android developer page](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tooling#layout-inspector)

[image]